# Excel GROUP MINIMUM VARIABLE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, max

```
    ID  Value   Valid   MAX
Group3  2   NO  8
Group3  8   YES 8
Group1  4   YES 4
Group4  2   NO  1
Group4  3   NO  1
Group4  1   YES 1
Group1  2   YES 4
Group1  6   NO  4
Group3  4   YES 8
Group2  1   YES 3
Group3  7   NO  8
Group2  3   YES 3
Group5  7   NO  1
```

I have 'ID' 'VALUE' and can make 'MAX' by =MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B))   BUT I wish to make a variable 'ISMAX' that equals to 'a' if the row is the ID max or 'b' if it is not AND the only values that count are ones where "YES" is in "VALID" column.

Answer (score 1):

Try `=IF(MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,"YES")=B2,"a","b")`

[image]

For Group 1 4 is the max valid value.
Otherwise (excluding the valid=yes-check) it would be 6.

Comment: thank you it works perfect but can you see my update question I forgot a important piece of this

Comment: thank you but that addition "YES" for maxifs didn't change result

Comment: Yes Basically I wish to restict the MAXIFS ONLY to rows when Valid = "YES"

Comment: Did you adjust the whole formula: `=IF(MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,C:C,"YES")=B2,"a","b")` - for me it works - I will update the screenshot accordingly

Comment: I did like you show but it gives same answer

Comment: i see how it does not work. if there is matches in VALUES then it does not work. but that is why i only want to use the rows with "YES"

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What would you expect to be the correct outcome?